# How to send a FQDN as resource id in http delete method

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey

I have a table with fully qualified domain names as the primary key. I am setting up a REST api to manage the db (mainly inserts and deletes), but I have run into a problem sending an http DELETE request with a url as a path parameter.

Example:

REST api servlet container =  `http://www.someapp.com/api`
Member resource id to be deleted = `www.anotherapp.com/home`

I want to send an http DELETE request to `http://www.someapp.com/api/www.anotherapp.com/home`

The Jersey resource path is:

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{url}")
public void deleteUrl(@HeaderParam("request-origin") String origin, 
        @PathParam("url") String url){
    // some stuff
}
```

When I try this I get a 404 error. How can I send a FQDN as resource id in http DELETE method?

Comment: you need to escape the / characters in your path.

Comment: Which characters? Dot and slash?

Comment: Only /. / separates pathname components in JAX-RS, not .

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Need to write a js function to dynamically find and escape the /

Comment: I actually found a way to solve it on the JAX-RS side by adding a regex to the @Path annotation: `@Path("/{url  : .+}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bmargulies mentions in the comments, the error was caused by unescaped `/` characters in the path parameter. The solution that worked for me was to add a regex to the `@Path` annotation in Jersey.

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{url : .+}")
public void deleteUrl(@HeaderParam("request-origin") String origin, 
        @PathParam("url") String url){
    // some stuff
}
```